# websites images breaks when changing url in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am facing a problem in react js. There is no problem if I am in product page like following url

http://localhost:3000/productDetails/

But if I am going the url like this

http://localhost:3000/productDetails/5

Then my web pages broken and some images not loading. I also noticed the url of images also changes for the above urls. Here is the difference of images urls.

http://localhost:3000/image/6.jpg
http://localhost:3000/productDetails/image/6.jpg

I do not know what to do. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you please share your css / html with those images? Most probably they have some relative paths like: ```url: './6.jpg``` which cause the issue

Comment: yes , my image src like <img src="image/logo_head_left.png" alt="company logo"/>

Answer (score 1):

This issues is caused by relative src paths to images which will be appended to current url. To fix it you should use absolute path in your sources.

Example:
`"/image/logo_head_left.png"` instead of `"image/logo_head_left.png"`